# How to scroll to top after 'add to cart' in OpenCart

Tags: php, jquery, opencart

I would like to scroll to the top after clicking "ADD TO CART" on my website. How do I do it in OpenCart?

Here is my website link.

http://www.camelkart.in/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=111

Comment: Please, add the relevant code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

On click of the cart button, show your pop up like:

```
$("your popup element").show();
```

And move to the top by:

```
 window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Comment: I am new to opencart and have very less knowledge in php. Could you guide me on how to implement this code?